# Spark select statement on dataframe is causing the job to shut down without logging any error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark here and trying my hands on Spark. In my project I am trying to read data from S3 bucket and then create dataframe from which I am filtering based on a condition. The line from which select option is being put the spark job shuts down without any error and I don't have the filtered frame. Tried giving print schema that is also working fine, even it prints the data frame count but select query or write to S3 request is encountered the shutdown hook is being called and the entire process shuts down.
The command I am firing :-

```
    spark-submit --master "local[*]" --class com.test.action.myjob test_job.jar
```

The logs for that particular event is

```
  2020-07-17 14:23:27 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Pruning directories with: 
  2020-07-17 14:23:27 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Post-Scan Filters: isnotnull(fieldname#11),(name#11 = my_filter_condition)
  2020-07-17 14:23:27 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Output Data Schema: struct<metadata-sdk_timestamp: string, name: string, object_data-_scheduled_rental_requests_enabled: boolean, object_data-account_group: string, object_data-action: string ... 423 more fields>
  2020-07-17 14:23:27 INFO  FileSourceScanExec:54 - Pushed Filters: IsNotNull(name),EqualTo(fieldname,my_filter_condition)
  2020-07-17 14:23:27 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Same job when tried ran successfully on a different set of data produces logs as below :-

```
2020-07-17 15:24:13 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Pruning directories with: 
2020-07-17 15:24:13 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Post-Scan Filters: isnotnull(name#11),(fieldname#11 = my_filter_condition)
2020-07-17 15:24:13 INFO  FileSourceStrategy:54 - Output Data Schema: struct<metadata-sdk_timestamp: string, name: string, object_data-account_group: string, object_data-action: string, object_data-additional_mileage_charge: double ... 289 more fields>
2020-07-17 15:24:13 INFO  FileSourceScanExec:54 - Pushed Filters: IsNotNull(name),EqualTo(fieldname,my_filter_condition)
2020-07-17 15:24:13 DEBUG S3AFileSystem:60 - op_exists += 1  ->  3
2020-07-17 15:24:13 DEBUG S3AFileSystem:60 - op_get_file_status += 1  ->  48
2020-07-17 15:24:13 DEBUG S3AFileSystem:1782 - Getting path status for s3a:
```

We could see from the logs that at certain point when filter option is applied then the load is failing in first case.

The code snippet is below :-

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.read
        .option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .format("parquet")
        .load("s3//path")
println(dataFrame.count())
dataFrame.printSchema()
val print_data_frame = dataFrame.select("name")
print_data_frame.show(100)
```

Reading from S3 is working fine, count is also being printed schema too. But the select statement when called the spark job shuts down. Have tried lot of things nothing work .
What could be the reason of failure , I tried putting the logs at debug level but it doesn't give me anything why the filter option is failing . Any clue or hint  is great.

Comment: please increase your memory and try again, my guess is that data is heavy

Comment: Are you running Spark on premises or in some cloud service?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comments, this looks like memory issue. My suggestion would be to try running the program with lesser data on S3 first and then you can run on your actual data.